# Converting MIPS syscalls to getchar(); or scanf(); in C

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I'm converting some MIPS code to C and I'm confused about if the following syntax are equivalent.

```
li $v0, 11 //print character
syscall


li $v0, 12 //Read character
syscall


putchar(); //print a character 

getchar(); //Read a character
```

How about the `scanf();`  what is the equivalent syntax for this in MIPS?

**Edit**

I'm using MARS simulator.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by equivalent. SPIM implements system call 11 using `vfprintf` with a `"%c"` format string, and system call 12 using `read`. But using `putchar` and `getchar` would probably be easier.

Answer (score 0):

No, those are of course not "equivalent", since they also have arguments and return values which you haven't touched upon.

Also, there must be some underlying ROM or operating system on the MIPS that you're not specifying; a processor architecture by itself doesn't have "sys calls", those are for "the (operating) system" to implement. So which is it?

Comment: I'm using MARS simulator

Answer (score 0):

getchar() and putchar() would be more equivalent than scanf() and printf() because the latter take other arguments.